# Communicate to Rest server on other domain with Javascript

Tags: javascript, http, rest, session

I have this scenario, a Javascript client connects to a Rest sever that expose JSONP API's on another domain.

My question would be

- If the server is stateless, then even if the server has a `/session`
  API to generate session key, would it be meaningful for the other succeeding requests?

That is, how can a server side session on another domain usable in a pure front-end scenario. In a typical web app, the front-end is loaded from the same domain thus, when app loads and authenticates, session objects may be generated.

Yet for this kind of situation the client (is a pure Frontend) that lives somewhere else in the internet and not in the same domain of the Rest Server. Session is not really applicable is that correct?

Comment: I never seen session(via cookies) for cross domain call. Cross domain api call always works with API key.

Comment: OAuth is a way of authenticating user and getting information about the user. However user's session should be maintained in your server.

Comment: What I need is for a javascript application to access resources from other domain. Not really get user information.